# trying to insert multi select input with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, laravel

I am trying to store multi-select input with ajax in Laravel but I am getting this error

```
{message: "Function name must be a string", exception: "Error", …}
```

here is my blade code

```
<select class="" multiple="" id="medicine_pills" name="medicine_pills[]">
    <option value="2">test</option>
    <option value="2">test</option>
</select>

var medicine_pills = $('#medicine_pills').val();
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ url('medicine') }}',
    type: "post",
    data: {
        '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        'medicine_pills': medicine_pills,
        'last_appointment_id': last_appointment_id,
    },
```

in controller

```
$medicines = request()->post('medicine_pills');

foreach ($medicines as $iteam) {
    echo $medicines;
    $user = Medicine::create([
        'medicines_cats' => $iteam,
        'appointmen_id' => $last_appointment_id,
    ]);
```

Comment: Please share what you get on `dd($medicines)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="" multiple="" id="medicine_pills" name="medicine_pills[]">
    <option value="2">test</option>
    <option value="2">test</option>
</select>

var medicine_pills = $("input[name='medicine_pills[]']").val();
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ url('medicine') }}',
    type: "post",
    data: {
        '_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        'medicine_pills': medicine_pills,
        'last_appointment_id': last_appointment_id,
    },
```

Please try with this.

Comment: This may be the answer, but adding an explanation would greatly increase the quality of your answer.  What did you do, and why do you think it will help? *Explain* your answer, so future visitors of all skill levels can learn from it.  [Code-only answers are considered low quality on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers).